# Show messages from tablet Samsung Galaxy tab 3 on logcat

Tags: android, logcat, galaxy-tab

I have developed an Android app using mapsforge, it works perfect on tablet acer Android 4.0.3 but not  works on tablet Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 and  on Galaxy dont show the logs on logcat, in fact dont show anything, i think that i have problems  when the map is deployed. I am using alogcat app and abd from terminal but it dont show the logs for my app.

I am trying put on Manifiest (android:debuggable=true).

How can i show the logs on logcat in Galaxy tab 3?

Any ideas

Comment: So you mean USB debugging is connected but logs are not shown? If you do "adb devices" command, can you see the device in the list?

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the debuggable and make sure usb debugging is on

Answer (score 0):

first  select android device tab make sure you can see you device in list,if you debug one more device select Galaxy Tab 3,if do`nt work ,you may need be restart you IDE. the last way is  restart you Galaxy Tab 3,because i have face the same silution,after restart device i solve it, good luck ,hope userful