# Debug messages getting logged as warning from Samsung device in logcat

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

I am using *Samsung hardware devices(Tab2 and S3)* for testing purpose.

I am using eclipse galileo.observed that all `Log.d(tag,message)` are getting printed as warning in LogCat.
But when ran the same code on emulator all logs are printed correctly as debug level.

I have already tried solution given in below posts:

1> [Logcat won't display Log.d messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908001/logcat-wont-display-log-d-messages)

2> [Show messages from tablet Samsung Galaxy tab 3 on logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843273/show-messages-from-tablet-samsung-galaxy-tab-3-on-logcat)

3> [Android logcat logging only info level on real device. Cannot get debug messages, not even unhandled exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739428/android-logcat-logging-only-info-level-on-real-device-cannot-get-debug-messages) (Solution is for `Huawei Y300 (Y300-0100)` )

Nothing worked.Then I started emulator and even my phone was connected. I observed that debug is not enabled for device but was enabled for emulator.
[image: Screenshot_ device choose]

Also,provided i am inside my company's firewall so can't update eclipse to JUNO.Need some help in the present development scenario if possible.Please help.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking here.  But you should probably try the command line version of adb and adb logcat to get a clearer sense of the problem.  Perhaps you need to toggle USB debugging on the phone off and back on, clear debug certificates and then re-accept the PCs, etc.  And escalate the issue of being unable to access tool updates; not that updating eclipse is likely your solution, but you do need access to the tools required for the job they expect you to do.

Comment: have you enabled `USB DEBUGGING` in `DEVELOPER OPTION` from settings in you device?

Comment: have you enabled debugging (android:debuggable="true") in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: As Chris Stratton said, open a terminal and run "adb logcat -s your.package.name:v". Then post the output and your code that belongs to it.